# Linking Tableau to a Salesforce report with automatic refreshing

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

Tableau is currently lacking an out-of-the-box connector for Salesforce Reports. I am sure this will change at some point, but who knows when?

Currently it has a connector for individual Salesforce Objects, but if the schema is particularly complicated, Tableau will have issues replicating that. Connecting directly to a report would solve that issue, but the only way to do that as far as I can tell is to download the report as an Excel or csv file and manually upload it to Tableau. Any other automatic solution runs into Salesforce's 2000 row limit for querying reports, which is not enough for what we need to do.

So, how do I link Tableau directly to a Salesforce report without having to refresh it manually?

Answer (score 1):

We actually managed to solve this through Microsoft Power Automate!

Essentially, we found that we can use Power Automate to make an HTTP GET request to the URL that links to the download of the report itself. For us, it looked like this:

`https://<domain>.salesforce.com/<report_id>?csv=1&exp=1&enc=UTF-8&isdtp=p1`